# Random number generator for case distinctions

Tags: conditionals, random-numbers

I would like to compile a snippet of code using a random case distinction. How can I implement that?

No-LaTeX pseudocode:

```
x = rand(1,4) // random number between 1 and 4
if( x == 1 )
Let us talk about apples!
else if( x == 2 )
Let us talk about pears!
else if( x == 3 )
Let us talk about plums!
else 
Let us talk about cherries!
```

What is the best way this can be implemented? I would like to use it within math environments as well.

Comment: If you have an uptodate (2020) TeXlive then there is the `random.tex` file for generating and using random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a command that outputs a random item from a list.

The items must be braced if they contain more than one token.

There are two versions: the first defines a command (suitable for long lists), the second can be used inline.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makerandomchoice}{mm}
 {
  \shuhalo_random_choice_make:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\randomchoice}{m}
 {
  \shuhalo_random_choice:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \shuhalo_random_choice_make:Nn
 {
  \cs_new:Npn #1
   {
    \shuhalo_random_choice:n { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \shuhalo_random_choice:n
 {
  \tl_item:nn { #1 } { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { \tl_count:n { #1 } } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makerandomchoice{\talk}{
  {Let us talk about apples!}
  {Let us talk about pears!}
  {Let us talk about plums!}
  {Let us talk about cherries!}
}
\makerandomchoice{\letter}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\begin{document}

\talk

\talk

\talk

\talk

\talk

\letter\letter\letter\letter\letter\letter\letter\letter
\letter\letter\letter\letter\letter\letter\letter\letter

\randomchoice{{Pear}{Apple}{Plum}{Cherry}}

\randomchoice{{Pear}{Apple}{Plum}{Cherry}}

\randomchoice{{Pear}{Apple}{Plum}{Cherry}}

\randomchoice{{Pear}{Apple}{Plum}{Cherry}}

\end{document}
```

Spaces between items are ignored.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use such a capability inline? It seems that your solution requires putting content in the header section. I am thinking of something that replaces the uncomment-recompile-comment-cycle, so to speak.

Comment: @shuhalo I added the “inline” version.

Comment: This does the job well. Just out of curiousity, what is the random number generator used? I suspect it is biased on my system.

Comment: While sufficient for my purposes, it does not seem to mesh well with blank lines within the argument. I'd be curious how that can be fixed.

Comment: @shuhalo Use `{+m}` instead of `{m}` in both main definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you know R and `knitr`, this can be achieved with some very similar to your pseudocode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<fruit-roulette,echo=F,cache=FALSE>>=
x    <- sample(1:4, 1) 
talk <- if( x == 1 ) {"apples"} else {
        if( x == 2 ) {"pears"}  else {
        if( x == 3 ) {"plums"}  else {
        if( x == 4 ) {"cherries"}}}} 
@

Because $x=\Sexpr{x}$, let us talk about \Sexpr{talk}! 

\end{document}
```

In each compilation the LaTeX text could change, being one possible result:

---

[image: mwe]

---

As you see here,  the `\Sexpr{}` can be use in math and text modes, but take into account that the R output  will be formatted according to LaTeX rules (e.g., being the `foo` R object "big apples", `\Sexpr{foo}` or `$\mbox{\Sexpr{foo}}$` will produce just  "big apples", but `\Sexpr{talk}` will produce "*bigapples*".