# How do random numbers in expl3 Syntax work?

Tags: expl3, random-numbers

This is a follow-up to a prior [question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539921/random-number-generator-for-case-distinctions). The same device is used in a number of other randomness-related questions here though.

What exactly is the source of (pseudo)randomness when writing

```
\int_rand:nn
```

in the expl3 syntax?

Where can you find documentation on this? I was unsuccessful in finding information on that online. Furthermore, can you set seeds for the pseudorandom number generator, similar to  `rand` and `srand` in `C`?

Answer (score 3):

You can find details on it in the documented source. You get it with `texdoc source3`. 
The random integers are implemented with the help of the random floating numbers so you should read in `9.3 (Floating point expressions / Operations)` about the `rand` and `randint` operator. How to set the seed is described  there too.

In `36 l3fp-random Implementation` you will find the comments about the mathematical background.